# Kubernetes clusters should disable automounting API credentials

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cli

I have deployed a model to a Kubernetes cluster and I'm getting this security alert - Kubernetes clusters should disable automounting API credentials.
I looked up some documents in google and it seems like I could disable it by running  automountServiceAccountToken: false.

But not sure where I could run this command and if there is any other commands I need to run besides that.

Thank you! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can set the automountServiceAccountToken field to false in the pod spec for your deployment.modify your deployment YAML file as below:

 If you're managing Kubernetes resources using the kubectl command line tool, you can update the deployment with the kubectl patch command. kubectl patch deployment your-deployment-name -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"automountServiceAccountToken": false}}}}'

Comment: deployment YAML file: apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: my-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

Comment: Hi @Imran, thank you for your response! Could I know where I could find the pod spec file..? is it in AML studio? (sorry I worked with some other team members and didn't deploy the model to the cluster on my own..) thank you so much for your help again

Comment: if you did't create the YAML file u can use the kubectl CLI to retrieve the YAML file for your deployment  `kubectl get deployment <deployment-name> -o yaml > deployment.yaml` This cmd will retrieve the YAML file for ur deployment and save it file named deployment.yaml in your current directory Once you have the YAML file, you can modify it to disable automounting of API credentials by setting the automountServiceAccountToken field to false

Answer (score 0):

kubectl get pods/`<podname>` -o yaml > file.yaml

Open the file.yaml using your favorite editor. Then:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: build-robot
automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

or

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

PS: If both the ServiceAccount and the Pod's .spec specify a value for automountServiceAccountToken, the Pod spec takes precedence.

More info:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/